# Applet no se visualiza en navegador

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, applet

He creado un Applet muy simple y necesito mostrarlo dentro de una aplicación web de Java en Netbeans. Estoy utilizando XAMPP para inicializar un servidor local con Tomcat.

El applet se puede correr bien desde el IDE; pero cuando intento correr el JSP, no se muestra nada y no recibo ningún mensaje de error. La página web carga en el navegador con el título, pero el applet nada de nada.

El proyecto del applet **si** esta en el "packaging" de las propiedades del proyecto de la aplicación web. Chrome y Mozilla no muestran nada, IE me dice que *se bloqueo el software porque no se puede comprobar el fabricante*.  He agregado ya la URL a los sitios seguros de la configuración de Java en PC también.

He intentado agregarlo de esta forma:

```
<%@page language="java" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Applet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Y ahora, un applet:</h1>
        <applet code="Dibujos.Appletv2" archive="AppletCompOne.jar" width="500" height="400"/> 
    </body>      
</html>
```

Y de esta otra forma:

```
<%@page language="java" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Applet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Y ahora, un applet:</h1>
        <jsp:plugin type="applet" archive="AppletCompOne.jar" code="Appletv2.class" width="500" height="400">
            <jsp:fallback>
                <p>No carga :(</p>
            </jsp:fallback>
        </jsp:plugin>
    </body>      
</html>
```

Cualquier ayuda se agradece. 
(Soy nuevo. Piedad, por favor)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox y Chrome dejaron de dar soporte al [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) que usaban los plugins para comunicarse con el navegador, por lo que es **imposible** lanzar applets en esos navegadores, es una tecnología obsoleta. Lo mismo ocurre para Edge.

Si estás manteniendo una aplicación antigua empresarial, te recomiendo que intentes presionar para usar otra solución. Si estás intentando crear un nuevo Applet, olvídalo: la clase Applet en Java 9 ya está marcada como *Deprecated* y en futuras versiones desaparecerá, se considera una tecnología obsoleta.

Answer (score -1):

en estos momentos el único navegador que soporta applet es internet explorer, siempre y cuando este firmado digitalmente, existe algunas formas de simular la firma de código, pero no la recomiendo porque no funciona bien.

te recomiendo usar otro tipo de tecnología, como dice el amigo de arriba esta obsoleto.